# Как в SQL получить данные, на которые ссылается foreign key?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица сотрудников EMPLOYEE, в которой каждому сотруднику соответствует id отдела, к которому он относится (DEPARTMENT_ID). Я сделал этот айдишник ссылкой (foreign key) на другую таблицу (главную, DEPARTMENT), содержащую перечень отделов (название отдела и его айдишник).
Как в SQL-запросе получить вот то самое название отдела, на которое ссылается его айдишник, указанный напротив каждого сотрудника в таблице EMPLOYEE?
Т.е. нужно получить перечень сотрудников и НАЗВАНИЕ отдела, которому соответствует DEPARTMENT_ID.

Comment: используйте join и выводите столбец с наименованием из второй таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого необходимо использовать join.

Пример схемы БД:

```
create table DEPARTMENT (
  ID serial primary key,
  NAME text
);

create table EMPLOYEE (
  ID serial primary key,
  NAME text,
  DEPARTMENT_ID int references DEPARTMENT(ID)
);
```

Пример запроса:

```
select EMPLOYEE.NAME as NAME,
       DEPARTMENT.NAME as DEPARTMENT_NAME
from EMPLOYEE
join DEPARTMENT on DEPARTMENT.ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```